# How do I define fire_event, undefined fire_event error

Tags: php

I'm cleaning up all the errors in an old script and I'm getting one that says `undefined function fire_event`. How do I define fire_event. everything works fine but i've turned on error_reporting(E_ALL); to fix all hidden errors

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function fire_event() in /home/social/public_html/includes/dologin.php on line 96**

```
    if (strpos($en['redirect'],'index.php?req=login')) unset($en['redirect']);
    $redirect = (isset($en['redirect']) && $en['redirect']!='' ? $en['redirect'] : constant('dir').'members.html');

    fire_event('member_login',$line['m_id']);
    header('Location: '.$redirect);
    exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to be some custom function and we don't know what belongs in there. Search all source files, because you most likely removed or changed a dependency and/or `include()` or `required()` line.

Comment: thanks, I just commented it out and everything else appears to be working fine. I'll keep an eye out for any related errors.